# Placing three flip-boxes in a circular form

Tags: html, css

I wish to place three flip-boxes in a circular form. Below is the code I got:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-box-front, .flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

/* position of parent-flipbox */
.first-flipbox{
  width:471px;
  height:471px;
  position: relative;
} 

/* child flipbox positions */
.first-flipbox{ left: 184px; top: -38px; }
.second-flipbox{ left: 376px; top: 295px; }
.third-flipbox{ left: -8px; top: 295px; }
```

```html
<div class="first-flipbox">
<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <h2>Front Side</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <h2>Back Side</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="second-flipbox">
<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <h2>Front Side</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <h2>Back Side</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="third-flipbox">
<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <h2>Front Side</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <h2>Back Side</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The issue is that I can't succeed in placing the second and third flip-boxes at their respective place (i.e facing eachother and on the same horizontal line, below the first one) as I succeeded in placing the first flip-box at its position. I've looked through several times and I can't still figure out the typo.

Thanks for some help.

Comment: Some fairly small changes to get close to what you want. Remove the width and height from .first-flipbox, it's causing the div to think it has a considerably larger size than its actual content. Change .second-flipbox and .third-flipbox to have display: inline-block. At present since your stuff is in divs it will put each thing on new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to use absolute positions not relative however I added a wrapper div around all items which has relative position. Also Add `position:absolute` and `display:inline-block` to all three boxes as the `div`s are blocks by default;

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-box-front, .flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

/* position of parent-flipbox */
.first-flipbox{
  width:471px;
  height:471px;
  position: relative;

} 

/* child flipbox positions */
.first-flipbox{   position:absolute;display:inline-block;left: 184px; top: -38px; }
.second-flipbox{   position:absolute;display:inline-block;left: 376px; top: 295px; }
.third-flipbox{  position:absolute;display:inline-block; left: -8px; top: 295px; }
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">

  <div class="first-flipbox">
  <div class="flip-box">
    <div class="flip-box-inner">
      <div class="flip-box-front">
        <h2>Front Side</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-box-back">
        <h2>Back Side</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <div class="second-flipbox">
  <div class="flip-box">
    <div class="flip-box-inner">
      <div class="flip-box-front">
        <h2>Front Side</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-box-back">
        <h2>Back Side</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <div class="third-flipbox">
  <div class="flip-box">
    <div class="flip-box-inner">
      <div class="flip-box-front">
        <h2>Front Side</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-box-back">
        <h2>Back Side</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```